A certain inequality involving square roots of polynomials
I want to prove the inequality
$$\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2}\Big[y^2(9x - 6) - 9x^2 + 9x^3\Big]+ y^2(16x^2 - 16x + 7)\\
&- \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\Big[9x + y^2(9x - 3) + \sqrt{(x - 1)^2 + y^2}(9x^2 - 9x + 6y^2) - 18x^2 + 9x^3\Big]\\
& + 9x^2 - 18x^3 + 9x^4 + 7y^4 \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
for real and nonzero $x,y$. Is this inequality true? How does one go about showing it?

Please double check I haven't messed up the reformatting of the formula. How did this even arise, may I ask?

It would seem that expressions of this form for various coefficients are sometimes always positive and sometimes always negative. In this case it seems that these particular coefficients result in the expression being always positive, but showing that that's true, and moreover, showing which collections of coefficients always make the expression positive or negative, is not something I know how to do.

But why this specific formula, instead of any number of others? What drove the choice of these terms? They cannot be chosen at random, no?

A human verifiable proof.
The desired inequality is written as
$$p A + B - q(C + p D) \ge 0 \tag{1}$$
where
\begin{align*}
    &p := \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}, \quad q := \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \quad A := y^2(9x - 6) - 9x^2 + 9x^3, \\
    &B := y^2(16x^2 - 16x + 7) + 9x^2 - 18x^3 + 9x^4 + 7y^4, \\
    &C := 9x + y^2(9x - 3) - 18x^2 + 9x^3, \quad D := 9x^2 - 9x + 6y^2.
\end{align*}
Clearly $B \ge 0$. We claim that $pA + B \ge 0$. Indeed, we have
\begin{align*}
    B^2 - p^2 A^2 &= 49\,{y}^{8}+ \left( 143\,{x}^{2}-116\,x+62 \right) {y}^{6} \\
    &\qquad + \left( 139
    \,{x}^{4}-224\,{x}^{3}+165\,{x}^{2}-44\,x+13 \right) {y}^{4} \\
    &\qquad + 9x^2(5x^2-2x+2)(x-1)^2{
        y}^{2}\\
    &\ge 0.
\end{align*}
(Note: All the coefficients, as a polynomial in $y$, are non-negative.)  The claim is proved.
To prove (1), it suffices to prove that $(pA + B)^2 - q^2(C + pD)^2 \ge 0$, or
$$Mp + N \ge 0 \tag{2}$$
where
\begin{align*}
    M &:= 18\,{x}^{5}{y}^{2}+36\,{x}^{3}{y}^{4}+18\,x{y}^{6}-90\,{x}^{4}{y}^{2}-
    138\,{x}^{2}{y}^{4}-48\,{y}^{6}\\
    &\qquad +144\,{x}^{3}{y}^{2}+156\,x{y}^{4}-72\,
    {x}^{2}{y}^{2}-84\,{y}^{4},\\
    N &:= 13\,{y}^{8}+ \left( 44\,{x}^{2}-98\,x+89 \right) {y}^{6}\\
    &\qquad + \left( 49\,{
        x}^{4}-206\,{x}^{3}+327\,{x}^{2}-242\,x+85 \right) {y}^{4} \\
    &\qquad + 18x^2(x-1)^2(x-2)^2{
        y}^{2}.
\end{align*}
Note that if $\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2} = 0$, then $x=1, y= 0$ and $Mp + N = 0$. In what follows, assume that $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} > 0$.
We use the parametrization
$$x := 1 + r \cdot \frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \quad y := r \cdot \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \quad r > 0, t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
We have $p = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} = r$ and
\begin{align*}
    Mp + N &= \frac{r^6(t - 1)^2(t + 1)^4(13t^2 + 10t + 13)}{(t^2+1)^4}\cdot g(r, t)
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
    g(r, t) &:= \left(r + \frac{1}{r} - \frac{5(3t^2+2t+3)(t-1)^2}{(t^2+1)(13t^2+10t+13)}\right)^2\\[6pt]
    &\qquad - \frac{36(t+3)(3t+1)(t+1)^2(t^2+t+1)^2}{(13t^2+10t+13)^2(t^2+1)^2}.
\end{align*}
It suffices to prove that $g(r, t)\ge 0$ for all $r > 0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (easy, by letting $u := r + 1/r \ge 2$; we only need to consider the case $(t+3)(3t+1) > 0$).
We are done.

This problem is one of real algebraic geometry. As such, it admits a completely algorithmic solution. In Mathematica, such algorithms are realized by commands such as Reduce. Using this command, one finds in about 0.05 sec that (i) the left-hand side of your inequality is $\ge0$ for all real nonzero $x,y$ and (ii) the left-hand side of your inequality is $0$ for real nonzero $x,y$ iff $x=1/2$ and $y=\pm\sqrt3/2$.
Here is an image of the corresponding Mathematica notebook:


My second solution (simpler than my first solution).
Remark. Inspired by @Toni Mhax's solution, we came up with this solution.
Let $a := \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2},\, b := \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.
We have
$x = \frac{b^2 - a^2 + 1}{2}, \, y^2 = b^2 - \big(\frac{b^2 - a^2 + 1}{2}\big)^2$.
The desired inequality is written as
$$
    \frac{y^2}{a + b + 1} F(a, b)\ge 0, \tag{1}$$
where $F(a, b) := -b^3 + (2a+2)b^2 + (2a^2-9a+2)b-a^3+2a^2+2a-1$.
Also, from $a\ge 0$ and $b^2 - \big(\frac{b^2 - a^2 + 1}{2}\big)^2 \ge 0$, we have
$|a-1| \le b \le a + 1$.
We can prove that
$$|a-1| \le b \le a + 1 \implies F(a, b) \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
A proof of (2) is given at the end which is easy but not so nice. Hope to see a nice proof of (2).
Thus, we are done.
$\phantom{2}$

    
We split into two cases.

Case 1. $\frac{13}{25} \le a \le \frac{19}{10}$

If $a = 1$, we have
$F(a, b) = (2-b)(b-1)^2 \ge 0$.
If $a \ne 1$, as a cubic in $b$, the discriminant of $F$ is given by
$$\Delta_b(F) = (125a^4-550a^3+847a^2-550a+125)(a-1)^2 < 0.$$
Also, we have $F(a, a+1) = 2(a+1))(a-1)^2 > 0$.
Thus, $F(a, b) \ge 0$ for all $b \le a + 1$.

Case 2. $(0 \le a < \frac{13}{25}) \lor (a > \frac{19}{10})$

We have
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial b} 
= -3b^2 + (4a+4)b + 2a^2-9a+2 \ge 0$ for all $|a-1| \le b \le a + 1$ (easy).
Thus, we have
$$F(a, b) \ge F(a, |a-1|) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    2(2a-1)^2 & 0 \le a \le 1 \\
    2a(a-2)^2 & a > 1.
\end{array}
\right. \ge 0.$$
In summary, (2) is true.

The answer of Iosif helps one try to change variables as the solution verify $x^2+y^2=1$.
This one is a bit long but oddly it has many powerful factorisation arguments.
So set $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=a$ and $y^2=a^2-x^2$ with $-a\le x\le a$. The inequality is then: $$\sqrt{a^2+1-2x}(9xa^2-6a^2-3x^2-9x^2a+9xa-6a^3+6ax^2)\ge (x^2-a^2)(16x^2-16x+7)+a(9x+9xa^2-3a^2+3x^2-18x^2)-9x^2+18x^3-9x^4-7a^4-7x^4+14a^2x^2.$$
We check first that both sides are negative or zero: the left side factor is $l(x)=-3(a+1)(a-x)(2a-x)\le 0$. The right side is equal to: $f(x)=2x^3-x^2(2+2a^2+15a)+x(16a^2+9a+9a^3)-7a^2-3a^3-7a^4$, $f(a)=0$, $f(-a)\le 0$ then notice that $f'(x)\ge 0$, for $-a\le x\le a$, also we can write $f(x)=(x-a)(2x^2-x(2+2a^2+13a)+7a+3a^2+7a^3)$.
Simplifying by $(a-x)$ and squaring both sides we get the polynomial inequality $$(x+a)(4x^3+x^2(10(a-1)^2)+x(-5a^4-20a^3+47a^2-20a-5)+13a^5-30a^4+35a^3-30a^2+13a)=(x+a)p(x)\ge 0.$$
The inequality is true for $x=\pm a$ (by factorisation), for the third-degree polynomial $p$, the derivative has one negative and one positive root, so we need only to check $p(x)\ge 0$ when $0\le x\le a$,
(for example, $-5a^4-20a^3+47a^2-20a-5 \le -5a^4-20a^3+50a^2-20a-5$ and this is $-5(x-1)^2(x^2+6x+1)\le 0$).
We take $p'(a)$, if $p'(a)\le 0$, $p$ is decreasing on $[0; a]$ and we are done, if $p'(a)>0$ we find the positive root $x_0$ of $p'(x)=0$ for $0\le x_0\le a$.
Simplifying $p'(a)$ gives $p'(a)=19a^2-5a^4-5$. We only check $\dfrac{19-\sqrt{261}}{10}\le a^2\le \dfrac{19+\sqrt{261}}{10} $ or for simplicity $0.53\le a\le 1.88;$
we have $x_0=\dfrac{\sqrt{40a^4-40a^3+9a^2-40a+40}-5(a-1)^2}{6}.$
Replacing, $p(x_0)$ has the same sign as $$475a^6-348a^5-1560a^4+2920a^3-1560a^2-348a+475-(80a^4-80a^3+18a^2-80a+80)\sqrt{40a^4-40a^3+9a^2-40a+40}$$
written as $t(a)-w(a)\sqrt{40a^4-40a^3+9a^2-40a+40}.$
Check that $$t(a)=475a^6-348a^5-1560a^4+2920a^3-1560a^2-348a+475\ge 475a^6-348a^5-1560a^4+2866a^3-1560a^2-348a+475\ge 0.$$
The last polynomial is $(a-1)^2(475a^4+602a^3-831a^2+602a+475)$  and it is nonnegative for $a\le 1$ and $a\ge 1$. Also $w(a)\ge 0$ as $a^4-a^3-a+1\ge 0$.
Take finally $t^2-w^2(40a^4-40a^3+9a^2-40a+40)$. This equals $$-243(a-1)^2(a+1)^2(a^2-5a+1)^2(125a^4-550a^3+847a^2-550a+125). $$
Verify only that $a^4+1-4.4(a^3+a)+\frac{847}{125}a^2=q(a)\le 0$ when $0.53 \le a \le 1.88$. Approximating its roots or the ones of its derivative or also consider $q(a)\le a^4+1-4.4(a^3+a)+6.8a^2=0.2(a-1)^2(5a^2-12a+5)$.
(Calculation are assisted by GeoGebra, online).

The idea of factorization is nice.

@RiverLi, thank you, i thought posting the way of reasoning (with factors) as it seems fluent for this inequality.

I am thinking if in this way there is a simpler proof.

@RiverLi I do not think so.

Suggestion for long expressions: You may use begin{align*} \end{align*}.  e.g. \begin{align*}
t(a) &= 475a^6-348a^5-1560a^4+2920a^3-1560a^2-348a+475\
&\ge 475a^6-348a^5-1560a^4+2866a^3-1560a^2-348a+475\
&\ge 0.
\end{align*}
